# Rails: How do I upload Paperclip image attachment to a DB from an unrelated controller + Strong params requirement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, paperclip, strong-parameters

**Help Request**

How do I upload image attachment to from an unrelated controller + Strong params requirements?

**Background**

> I have one controller, `Cars`.  I have two models `Car` and `Garage`.
>
> `Cars` controller creates a `Garage` object based on a user's vehicle
>   attributes (`users are from devise`).  There is no `Garages`
>   controller since the `Cars` controller create a new `@garage` object.
>
> The `Garage` model is where attributes from the `Car` model and other
>   values from the `Cars` controller are to be stored.
>
> The `Cars` show page list all the values
>
> Please know this application is working fine as it is *except* the
>   part where I would like to have a user upload a photo (`paperclip gem`) of their vehicle to the `garages` db.
>
> The way this application _supposed_functions is...
>
> 1. *cars/1* This show page contains a list of all vehicle's attributes and a button, `Browse...` and an `Add to Garage` button.
> 2. Selecting the `Browse...` button allows you to attach a photo of your vehicle. This is made possible using the `paperclip` gem.
> 3. Once your photo is attached, you can select the `Add to Garage` button.
> 4. The `Cars` controller creates a `Garage` object with several vehicle attributes including some from `devise` methods, instance variables
>      and places these values into the `garages` table.
>
> There are *NO* errors returned. All of the values are entered into the
>   `garages` db *except* for the *attached image*.

Below are the files

---

**cars/cars_controller.rb**

```
class CarsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_car

  def show
    @garage = Garage.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create    
    @garage = Garage.create( tech_id:  @car.service.tech.id, :customer_id: current_customer.id )
    if @garage.save
      redirect_to techs_path, notice:  "You car has been added to the garage!" 
    elsif 
      redirect_to tech_path, notice:  "Uh oh, flat tire!" 
    end
  end

  private

  def set_car
    @car = Car.find(params[:id])
  end

  def garage_params
    params.permit(:tech_id, :customer_id )
  end

end
```

---

**MODELS**

**models/car.rb** (unsure if the has_attached_file is needed in this model but added anyway)

```
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :service
  belongs_to :tech #added 5/27

  has_attached_file :garage_photo, styles: { medium: "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }#, :default_url => "/images/:style/missing.png"
  validates_attachment_content_type :garage_photo, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
end
```

**models/garage.rb**

```
class Garage < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :customer
  belongs_to :tech

  has_attached_file :garage_photo, styles: { medium: "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }#, :default_url => "/images/:style/missing.png"
  validates_attachment_content_type :garage_photo, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\Z/

end
```

---

**VIEWS**

**cars/show.html.erb**

```
<h2>Please review to add to garage </h2>
<b>Your garage tech:</b> <%= @car.service.tech.id %><br>
<b>ID:</b> <%= current_customer.id %><br>

<%= form_for @garage, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>
  <%= f.file_field :garage_photo %>
<% end %>


<%= button_to 'Add to Garage', tech_cars_path(tech_id: @car.service.tech.id, id: @car.id) %>
<%= link_to 'Back to tech', tech_path(@car.service.tech.id) %>
```

---

**Routes**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :customers, controllers: { sessions: 'customers/sessions' }, :path => ''
  devise_for :techs, controllers: { sessions: 'techs/sessions' } 
  #, :path => ''#, :path_names => { :sign_in => "login", :sign_out => "logout" }

  resources :techs, only: [:index, :show], shallow: true do
    resources :cars, only: [:show, :create]
  end

  resources :service_menus, :services, :garages
    root to: "home#index"
end
```

---

> **6-12 Add more details**

**_add_attachment_garage_photo_to_garages.rb** Migration file

```
class AddAttachmentGaragePhotoToGarages < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    change_table :garages do |t|
      t.attachment :garage_photo
    end
  end
end
```

---

**mysql> describe garages** *snippet*

```
| garage_photo_updated_at   | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| garage_photo_file_size    | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| garage_photo_content_type | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| garage_photo_file_name    | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL
```

|                |

---

**Please advise on the issues below:**

1. How can I upload image attachment to `garages` db from an unrelated `Cars` controller? Everything gets added to the `garages` db except for the `image attachment`. Please keep in mind there are no errors returned when `Add to Garage` button is selected. Is this a strong params issue?
2. Are strong params required in the `Cars` controller? If so, how do I assign the db `:keys` to instance `@variables`? I've searched all over but it's unclear how to assign instance variables to keys for strong params.

   `@garage = Garage.create(garage_params)`
   `params.permit(:tech_id, :customer_id )`
3. If possible, please provide any refactoring approaches you may have.

Any help will be appreciated.
Please let me know if you require more details.

Thanks

Comment: While you don't need the `has_attached_file` in both models, I'm wondering what gem/code you're using to handle the upload. From the `has_attached_file` method, my sense is that it's Paperclip. Assuming you are using Paperclip or similar gem, what service is used and how did you configure it for your storage? My models with attached files explicitly state `storage: :fog` (we use Rackspace Cloud Files as our CDN).

Comment: Hi Craig, I am using the `paperclip` gem. All of my migrations are loaded and my associations I believe to be correct. I am not using a service. I have staged a dev environment locally on my laptop.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include `garage_photo` in strong parameter

cars/cars_controller.rb

```
class CarsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_car

  def show
    @garage = Garage.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create    
    @garage = Garage.create(garage_params)
    if @garage.save
      redirect_to techs_path, notice:  "You car has been added to the garage!" 
    elsif 
      redirect_to tech_path, notice:  "Uh oh, flat tire!" 
    end
  end

  private

  def set_car
    @car = Car.find(params[:id])
  end

  def garage_params
    params.permit(:tech_id, :customer_id, :garage_photo )
  end
end
```

cars/show.html.erb

```
<h2>Please review to add to garage </h2>
<b>Your garage tech:</b> <%= @car.service.tech.id %><br>
<b>ID:</b> <%= current_customer.id %><br>

<%= form_for @garage, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :tech_id, value: @car.service.tech.id %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :customer_id, value: current_customer.id %>
  <%= f.file_field :garage_photo %>
<% end %>

<%= button_to 'Add to Garage', tech_cars_path(tech_id: @car.service.tech.id, id: @car.id) %>
<%= link_to 'Back to tech', tech_path(@car.service.tech.id) %>
```

Comment: Hi @Prashant4020 - Unfortunately this does not work. Selecting the `Add to Garage` button not produce the desired results of _attaching a photo_ and it's also not including the key values in the `garages` db. I did realize one thing, the `tech.id` is not required since the `Garage` model  `belongs_to :tech`. Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

I'm hitting myself for not seeing it sooner.  Your view has no submit button for the same form that has the file upload field!
<%= button_to %> creates a completely separate form, basically encapsulates the entire form into a single button.  Therefore any value you provided in the form above will not be submitted when clicking this button.  Instead you should create a standard <%= f.submit "Submit" %> type button.

Comment: Hi Patrick, I did run a migration on the `garages` db. I am familiar with adding multiple models. Please see my updated post.

Comment: Hi Patrick - Please advise on how to encapsulate `Browse...` file button inside the `Add to Garage` button. I am unfamiliar with this process. Thank you for your response.

Comment: @Prashant4020 was on the right track, just didn't include a "Submit" button for the form.

   ....
  <%= f.file_field :garage_photo %>
  <%= f.submit "Submit" %>

<% end %>

Comment: Hi Patrick, I'm sorry but I've been trying to figure this out for the past couple of days. I've read numerous articles and resources but am unable to achieve the desired results. I'm unfamiliar with `submit` button since majority of my application mainly uses `link_to` helpers.  Closes I may have gotten was after submitting the form, Rails was asking where's the `update` action from the `garages` controller. There is no `garages` controller since there are no actions required of this. Also is there a way to avoid using hidden fields? A controller method to pass id's is preferred. Please advise

Comment: I am getting `The action 'update' could not be found for GaragesController`. There shouldn't be any updates by the `garages` controller because this file does not exist and should since the `cars` controller creates a new `garage` object and inserts attributes to `garage` model.